# Resize images in WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I was building an WYSIWYG editor for my website. I want to be able to resize images while user  is inserting image into text. How to do it ? This code is not working.

this  the code what i used.

```
function iImage(){  
   var imgSrc = prompt('Enter image location', '');  
   imgSrc.style.height='100px';
   imgSrc.style.width='50px';
   if(imgSrc != null){
       richTextField.document.execCommand('insertimage', false, imgSrc);   
   }
}
```

Comment: Bad news: You will have to write way more code than this to make it work.

Comment: edited my code look at it. it is not working.

Comment: why people unlike this post ?

Comment: I believe that's because there's nothing related to resizing images in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what sort of a WYSIWYG editor you are building or what those functions are doing, though at a glance I would advise to try setting the height and width **attributes**, not **styles** :

```
function iImage(){  
   var imgSrc = prompt('Enter image location', '');  
   imgSrc.height='100px';
   imgSrc.width='50px';
   if(imgSrc != null){
       richTextField.document.execCommand('insertimage', false, imgSrc);   
   }
}
```

As the corrseponding HTML should be

```
<img src="..." height="100px" width="500px">
```

not

```
<img src="..." style="height100px;width:500px;">
```

**EDIT:**

You can find the solution here:
[How to get the image element after insert using execCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507328/how-to-get-the-image-element-after-insert-using-execcommand)

Comment: I used WYSIWYG Rich Text HTML Editor so this code is can't put in WYSIWYG.

Comment: Wait, I thought you said you are building a WYSIWYG? Can you give a length to the editor you are using?

Comment: I mean i built WYSIWYG Rich Text HTML Editor. when editor put image to text it put its original size. so i want to make fix image size in WYSIWYG Rich Text HTML Editor

Comment: See the link in my edit, it gives a solution which may work for you

Comment: thank you its work. Somebody unlike my question but you helped me thank you much :)