# insert image in a iframe at caret location

Tags: javascript, html, createobject

For a rich text box. I want to insert a picture, selected by the user, at the caret's position.

First I tried that:

```
var loadImage = function(event) {
    var editor = editFrame.document;
    editor.execCommand("insertImage", false, event.target.files[0] );
};
```

I get only a broken link icon **but** at the current position in my iframe. No image. Then I've been told to try that:

```
var loadImage = function(event) {
    var editor  =  document.getElementById('editFrame');
    editor.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

Which is not what I want to do **but** in this case I don't have broken link problem and the image loads normally.

How can I get the best of the 2 worlds? :)

Can somebody explain me how to load an image where expected; at the caret position? I read some stuff but being a beginner it's all very confuse in my mind.

Using **only** javascript, please? I mean the solution offered by @David Bray works fine. But it uses JQuery and I have no clue what it's doing whatsoever... Or could someone translate me the JQuery into Javascript?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: Yes. But I'm learning so I wish I could do that in javascript before I try anything else... I mean I would like to understand what I'm doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take 10 and using [How to get the image element after insert using execCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507328/how-to-get-the-image-element-after-insert-using-execcommand)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <input type='file' id="imgInp" />

        </form>

        <div contenteditable id="doc">type here .. put you cursor here [.] and put an inmage in the queue</div>

        <script>
        function readURL(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    $('#doc').focus();
                    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, "<img src='" + e.target.result + "' />");
                    console.log( 'done');

                }

                reader.readAsDataURL( input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $("#imgInp").change(function() {
            readURL(this);

        });

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: but I don't really know what you are doing - are you using drag and drop to add images, it will work too, have to adapt a bit ..

Comment: I'm using the input type=file to get the name of the image file. And I would like that the image selected by the user shows at the caret's position. I had a quick look at the link you sent me. I think that will do the trick for me. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: sure - click that [.] to set the caret position, and I can post a iframe example too

Comment: I have to run and won't be able to try it right now... Yes you can send iframe example; I'll possibly learn a better way to do things...

Comment: I tried the solution proposed here: [lhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507328/how-to-get-the-image-element-after-insert-using-execcommand]  I still have the same problem. The insertion would be made at the caret position but I only get the icon for a broken link. What I don't understand is why the path is ok when using **editor.scr** of the second function (which is not what I want to do anyway); but not in my editor.execCommand of the first function which is where I would like the image to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JavaScript version of David Bray's script with various other changes. It's close enough to his answer to consider it just a different version but too different to just edit the original answer. One addition to highlight is I'm setting the input element value to empty after loading an image. If you don't do that and you delete an image it won't allow you to reload it.

```
const imgInp = document.getElementById('imgInp');
imgInp.onchange = function() {
  if (imgInp.files && imgInp.files[0]) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      // Works without the below focus, but you may need it if you modify it.
      document.getElementById('doc').focus();
      document.execCommand('insertImage', false, event.target.result);
      imgInp.value = "";
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(imgInp.files[0]);
  }
}
```